# How to implement the CAST keyword into a Convert(nvarchar,ISNULL query SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have the following stored procedure and when I execute it by passing in the necessary parameters, I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I believe this is due in part to one of the columns I have set is still functioning as a `nvarchar` when I am trying to set it to equal a `datetime` parameter. I need help trying to figure out how to implement the `CAST` function into the specified line:

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(25), ISNULL(T.ActivityDate, T.CreatedDate), 101) AS 'Call Date'
```

Below are my parameters, as well as the entire `SELECT` query of my stored procedure:

```
--USE LOCAL VARIABLES FOR SPEED
DECLARE @LocInstitutionID INT, @LocLastMod as datetime, @LocProcessTime as datetime

SET @LocProcessTime =  getutcdate();
SET @LocInstitutionID = @InstitutionID
SET @LocLastMod = @LastMod
--END USE LOCAL VARIABLES FOR SPEED

IF (@LocLastMod) IS NULL
BEGIN
    SET @LocLastMod = '2000-01-01 01:01:01.001'
END 

SELECT 
    @LocInstitutionID as 'institution_id',
    @LocProcessTime as 'RunTime', 
    CO.Institution_ID__c AS Institution_Student_ID,
    --I need to add CAST into the below line
    CONVERT(nvarchar(25), ISNULL(T.ActivityDate, T.CreatedDate), 101) AS 'Call Date',
    CAST(ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(T.[Description], 1, 999), ',', ';'), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''), '') AS NVARCHAR(1000)) AS 'Notes'
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM SFAPI_Task (NOLOCK) 
     WHERE ISNULL(IsDeleted, 0) = 0) T
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM SFAPI_Case (NOLOCK) 
     WHERE ISNULL(IsDeleted, 0) = 0) CA ON CA.Id = T.WhatId
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM SFAPI_Contact (NOLOCK) 
     WHERE ISNULL(IsDeleted, 0) = 0) CO ON CO.Id = CA.ContactId
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM SFAPI_Account (NOLOCK) 
     WHERE ISNULL(IsDeleted,0) = 0) A ON A.Id = T.Accountid 
WHERE 
    T.ringdna__Call_Disposition__c IS NOT NULL 
    AND CO.Cohort__c >= 1000010
    AND 'Call Date' >= @LOCLastMod
    AND CO.Institution_ID__c = @LocInstitutionID
ORDER BY 
    CO.LRAP_ID__c, ISNULL(T.ActivityDate, T.CreatedDate) DESC
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aside: using `NOLOCK` everywhere is a [bad habit to kick](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Comment: Your actual issue is that you cannot use expressions in the `SELECT` in a `WHERE`, and when you write `'Call Date' >= @LOCLastMod` you are actually comparing the *string* `'Call Date'` to `@LOCLastMod`, which obviously will not work. You likely want `WHERE ISNULL(T.ActivityDate, T.CreatedDate) >= @LOCLastMod`. You also want to switch to using `""` or `[]` for escaping identifiers (`AS [institution_id]`) and not mix this up with string literal syntax, as it enables confusion like this. Unfortunately T-SQL allows this, but don't do it.

Comment: Aside #2 - using nolock hint with **deprecated syntax** is even worse habit.

Comment: Aside #3: `USE LOCAL VARIABLES FOR SPEED` is cargo-culting in the extreme. All it does is disable parameter sniffing, which may or may not be desirable depending on the query, and `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` has the same effect and is arguably clearer